# ASUS X550J touchpad is not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, asus

My touchpad doesn't work. Here is the drivers list:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech Touchpad          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera: USB Camera                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And here is information from the system logs:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i touchpad
 
[    1.162999] input: FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input11
[  355.411331] psmouse serio4: Touchpad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.
```

The touchpad works well on Windows 10. Tell me if I should give more information about this issue which affects my Linux experience.